# How does the race condition described in the man-page of pselect occur

Tags: race-condition

I saw the following paragram in the man-page of pselect.

> The reason that pselect() is needed is that if one wants to wait for either a signal or for a file descriptor to become ready, then an atomic test is needed to prevent race conditions. (Suppose the signal handler sets a global flag and returns. Then a test of this global flag followed by a call of select() could hang indefinitely if the sig‐ nal arrived just after the test but just before the call. By contrast, pselect() allows one to first block signals, handle the signals that have come in, then call pselect() with the desired sigmask, avoiding the race.)

I don't understand how the race condition which is described in the paragraph occurs. Could you help make it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your signal handler sets a global g_Signaled when it is called, and then you have code like the following:

```
if( g_Signaled == false )
{
   // Suppose signal is fired here, after test of g_Signaled but before entering select.
   select( ... );
}
```

In this case, the select will block indefinitely, even though the signal has fired. pselect solves the problem because you can temporarily block the signal, test the flag, and then use pselect to atomically block and reenable the signal.